# Why is angularjs code slow?

Tags: angularjs

Is it normal, that angularjs ng-repeat takes 1.5 Seconds to render data from an rest api? The result consists of only 10 rows with in total 1KB of data. How can I improve the speed or where to look for the problem?

**ADDED INFOS:**

The rest request itself only takes 128ms if I run it directly on the browser.

This is a set of sample data you get from the rest api:

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "id": 1224,
            "name": "Schokolade-Vanille",
            "kcal": 35500,
            "displayName": "Schokolade-Vanille"
        },
        {
            "id": 23423,
            "name": "Naturreis Uncle Bens",
            "kcal": 34400,
            "displayName": "Naturreis Uncle Bens"
        },
        {
            "id": 123231,
            "name": "Paprikahendl",
            "kcal": 4100,
            "displayName": "Paprikahendl"
        },
        {
            "id": 434,
            "name": "Vanille Kugeln",
            "kcal": 53700,
            "displayName": "Vanille Kugeln"
        },
        {
            "id": 323423,
            "name": "Weihnachtstraum, Lindor-Kugeln",
            "kcal": 60800,
            "displayName": "Lindor-Kugeln"
        },
        {
            "id": 5435,
            "name": "Schokolade",
            "kcal": 4300,
            "displayName": "Schokolade"
        },
        {
            "id": 23213,
            "name": "Hühner-Nuggets",
            "kcal": 23400,
            "displayName": "Hühner-Nuggets"
        },
        {
            "id": 5534,
            "name": "Knödel, Kartoffel",
            "kcal": 1230,
            "displayName": "Knödel, Kartoffel"
        },
        {
            "id": 23233,
            "name": "Curvers",
            "kcal": 15400,
            "displayName": "Curvers"
        },
        {
            "id": 53434,
            "name": "Frites Original",
            "kcal": 14100,
            "displayName": "Frites Original"
        }
    ],
    "count": 12854
}
```

**NEW ADDED INFOS**

I have had a closer look now and found out, that not te repeat funktion is the problem.

I used the following code:

```
$scope.updateResultset = function() {
    $scope.result = Food.query({
        offset: $scope.offset,
        order_by: $scope.orderby,
        name: $scope.textfilter,
    },function(){
        console.log( "response " + (new Date().getTime() - start) );
    });
    $scope.offset = undefined;

    console.log( "updateResultset " + (new Date().getTime() - start) );start = new Date().getTime();
```

And get the following response:
response 435

But the request itself only takes 131ms. In my opinion, >300ms is a lot of time to waste in a single method?

Compared to my former version, where I showed a plan html list, which was replaced by jquery ajax response html, its much slower?

Comment: imo it's no a repeat problem may be your rest api ...

Comment: Is the problem the network request or the code processing? Angular is pretty quick, so it doesn't make sense that the problem would be there for something so simple, unless you're loading in a TON of other stuff. I'd look and see if I'm having issues with request speed and whether that can be optimized.

Comment: 10 rows shouldn't be an Angular problem unless each row has crazy # of watches.

Comment: So i have added some extra information - since the rest api only takes 125ms, I can't believe, that that is the problem

Comment: get developer tools and batarang and start exploring execution times and network requests.

Comment: i dont know why, but in chrome the whole thing is faster than in firefox

Comment: I have added more infos and a I tracked time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found out the problem. Not the repeatition of the 10 list items was the problem! As you can see in my question, I return not only the 10 results, but also the total amount of results. In my case it was '"count": 12854'.

On the same page, I have a pagination which was the part which slows down the whole page, since it had to render 1286 pager buttons (~12854/10). Now I only show 10 pager-buttons.

Answer (score 0):

As others indicated in the comments, the cause in the code is likely something else aside from ng-repeat.  However, here are other options to consider, if speed still seems like an issue for ng-repeat:

- quick-ng-repeat directive on github:  https://github.com/allaud/quick-ng-repeat
- ng-scroll, as part of angular-ui: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-utils/blob/master/modules/scroll/README.md

Comment: At the moment, I don't think its the repeat functionality any more. Maybe the query?